# TF2/Keras: Load a custom model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to continuously train a custom keras model. I have overwritten the [`train_step`](https://keras.io/examples/generative/dcgan_overriding_train_step/#override-trainstep) method like

```
class MyModel(keras.models.Model):

    def train_step(self, data):
        # doing my magic and returning metrics
```

Training works like a charm and gives good scores (yeah!). Then I [save the model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) to a tf-folder via `model.save`. I want to continue the training after I collect more data.

Then I load the model via

```
model = keras.models.load_model(saved_model)
```

However, model now is of type

```
tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional
```

and not of

```
MyModel
```

and is missing the custom `train_step` method. And of course when I call `fit` on the loaded model, everything breaks. How can I properly load the custom model in TF2/keras?

//edit: example code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf


class MyModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):

        x, y_true = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)

            loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true['a'], y_pred['a'])
            loss += tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true['b'], y_pred['b'])

            trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        return {'loss': loss}


def get_model():
    input = layers.Input(shape=(20, 1))
    x = layers.Conv1D(10, 3, activation='relu')(input)
    x = layers.Conv1D(20, 5, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(30, 7, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
    x_a = layers.Dense(2)(x)
    x_b = layers.Dense(3)(x)

    return MyModel(input, {'a': x_a, 'b': x_b}, name='MyModel')


def data_gen(n=640):
    for _ in range(n):
        features = tf.random.uniform(shape=(20, 1))
        labels = {
            'a': tf.random.uniform(shape=(2,), minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.float32),
            'b': tf.random.uniform(shape=(3,), minval=-1, maxval=0, dtype=tf.float32),
        }
        yield features, labels


ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_gen, output_types=(tf.float32, {'a': tf.float32, 'b': tf.float32}), output_shapes=((20, 1), {'a': (2,), 'b': (3,)}))
ds = ds.batch(64)

model = get_model()
model.compile('adam')
print(model)
model.summary()
model.fit(ds, epochs=5)
model.save('/tmp/mymodel')

# load
model = keras.models.load_model('/tmp/mymodel')
print(model)
model.summary()
model.fit(ds, epochs=5)
```

When executing this, I can train the model with the custom train_step. But after loading the saved model, the train step is lost and it cannot handle the output correctly. Therefore, it complains:

```
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./example.py", line 63, in <module>
    model.fit(ds, epochs=5)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
        self.trainable_variables)
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:2737 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:562 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /home/user/venv/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1271 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv1d/kernel:0', 'conv1d/bias:0', 'conv1d_1/kernel:0', 'conv1d_1/bias:0', 'conv1d_2/kernel:0', 'conv1d_2/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'].
```

Comment: Please show the output of `print("Loaded model:", loaded_model)` and You say `everything breaks.` Please show what broke, and attach the stack trace. Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the error log to understand the issue. And also check the custom objects save and load model [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#custom_objects). Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question with an example, which shows the problem.

Comment: Did the example show the error more clearly?

Comment: @papaya did the example show what explicitly went wrong? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @TFer Did the example show the error more clearly?

Comment: @Frankie777 A Keras Model is comprised of 2 things : `weights`, the `model architecture` (`MyModel` in your case). In order to succesfully load your model back, you have to save both the `architecture` & the `weight`. You can get them by `model.to_json()` and `model.get_weights()`. Save both of these ( `json` & `pkl` formats) and then load them back into your file as `loaded_model = model_from_json(arc) and loaded_model.set_weights(weights)`